# Percona cluster signal 11

Tags: mysql, percona

We have a percona cluster that is randomly getting signal 11's on different cluster nodes. I've exhausted everthing I know. Here's the .err file with the signal 11.

We're running Server version: 5.6.22-72.0-56 Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL), Release rel72.0, Revision 978, WSREP version 25.8, wsrep_25.8.r4150

```
11:01:11 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
Please help us make Percona XtraDB Cluster better by reporting any
bugs at https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-xtradb-cluster

key_buffer_size=536870912
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=17
max_threads=153
thread_count=6
connection_count=3
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 585348 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x4efe2a0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7fa21c1dfe50 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x8ccd9e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x36c)[0x6828dc]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf0a0)[0x7fa27a95e0a0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN8MDL_lock11Ticket_list13remove_ticketEP10MDL_ticket+0x19)[0x6748c9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN8MDL_lock13remove_ticketEMS_NS_11Ticket_listEP10MDL_ticket+0x46)[0x675066]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN11MDL_context12release_lockE17enum_mdl_durationP10MDL_ticket+0x1a)[0x675e5a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN22Item_func_release_lock7val_intEv+0x13b)[0x62b3bb]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN4Item4sendEP8ProtocolP6String+0x15c)[0x5eb2cc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN8Protocol19send_result_set_rowEP4ListI4ItemE+0xad)[0x67d76d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN11select_send9send_dataER4ListI4ItemE+0x5f)[0x6c35ff]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN4execEv+0x4d8)[0x6d90e8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12mysql_selectP3THDP10TABLE_LISTjR4ListI4ItemEPS4_P10SQL_I_ListI8st_orderESB_S7_yP13select_resultP18st_select_lex_unitP13st_select_lex+0x265)[0x71e645]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13handle_selectP3THDP13select_resultm+0x175)[0x71e8f5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x59a85f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0xb60)[0x6f8810]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_state+0x5c8)[0x6fd7f8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x6fd8f2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcj+0x1076)[0x6fef36]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0x202)[0x6ffbe2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0x2ad)[0x6d11dd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x42)[0x6d1262]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x140)[0xb195d0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x6b50)[0x7fa27a955b50]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fa278c4195d]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7fa24d0f7810): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 19719
Status: NOT_KILLED

You may download the Percona XtraDB Cluster operations manual by visiting
http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtradb-cluster/. You may find information
in the manual which will help you identify the cause of the crash.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem... do you resolve this?

Comment: if you can post more logs before th first line above we might find a probable cause.

Answer (score 1):

The only fix we found was to drop the version from 5.6 to 5.5.

Never had another signal 11 after that.

Thanks,

Comment: https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-8737

Answer (score 0):

> Table Locking
>
> Galera Cluster does not support table locking, as they conflict with
>   multi-master replication. As such, the LOCK TABLES and UNLOCK TABLES
>   queries are not supported. This also applies to lock functions, such
>   as GET_LOCK() and RELEASE_LOCK()... for the same reason.

http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/limitations.html